# computation and printing in a local Minitab macro is not working right. How to fix?

Tags: minitab

I am running a local macro in minitab 19.
The output is not correct for k7 (-.276 x 10)
How to fix? Output and input are below.
Also, it seems that printing constants in Minitab
requires constants to be in numerical order?
Is that correct?

Thanks.

Mary A. Marion

Output: Data Display
c4       0.972700
sigma    10.0000
B6       1.66900
B5       0.276000
UCL      16.6900
CL       9.72700
LCL      -16.6900

```
MACRO
SQCs k1 k2 k3 k4
# Problem 6.17 %SQCs .9727  10  1.669  .276.
mconstant k1 k2 k3 k4 k5 k6 k7
name k1 'c4' 
name k2 'sigma' 
name k3 'B6' 
name k4 'B5' 
name k5 'CL' 
name k6 'UCL' 
name k7 'LCL'
let k6 = k3*k2
let k5 = k1*k2
let k7 = k4*k2
PRINT k4 k2 k7
PRINT k1 k2 k3 k4 k6 k5 k7
endmacro
```